# Get data without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple chat box using php, javascript, ajax and mysql, and it works fine when I press send button the message shows up immediately without refreshing, but when I send a message from second browser I need to refresh the page to read the message.. So how to receive it without refreshing ? thanks

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use polling. Have the page use ajax to query the server every so often to see if there's a message to receive or not. On the page you:

1. use ajax once to send the message.
2. Make multiple repeated ajax calls every X seconds to ask the server if there is a new message to receive. The messages to receive must be stored on the server so that they can be sent when the page asks for the new messages. e.g.

.

```
setTimeout(ajaxFunctionToCheckForNewMessages, 10000);
function ajaxFunctionToCheckForNewMessages() {
    ajax.call...
    success: {
       // display any new messages received from the ajax call.
    }
}
```

Another solution would be push notifications which, as far as I can tell, will be much more difficult to implement.

Comment: I have already used Ajax, can you give me an exemple of code please

Comment: Currenly the page uses ajax once to send a message. Polling means multiple repeated ajax calls are made every X seconds to ask the server if there is a message to receive.